# How to send xml playload over http using wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying to send xml request over http using wso2 ESB. Per WSO2 ESB documentation, I am supposed to specify "pox" in transport type, however it doesn't seem to work. Is there any other option?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MyProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <ReceiptRequestMessage xmlns="">
                  <Header>
                     <Timestamp>2015-03-24 06:00:00.000000</Timestamp>
                     <Authentication>
                        <Identity>abc</Identity>
                        <SharedSecret>xyz</SharedSecret>
                     </Authentication>
                  </Header>
                  <RequestParameters>
                     <StartDate>2015-01-13 06:00:00.000000</StartDate>
                     <EndDate>2015-02-01 06:00:00.000000</EndDate>
                  </RequestParameters>
               </ReceiptRequestMessage>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="https://usertest.sciquest.com/apps/Router/ReceiptXMLExportFromRequest"
                        format="pox"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: What do you meanby pox doesn't seem to work? If you can share code you have tried and error logs occurred, it would helpful to give an answer. Hope you are using a proxy service and you have referred this documentation. It consist how to work with REST with proxy services. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-RESTClientandRESTService

Comment: I updated original question with actual proxy. It looks like easiest usecase. I am able to send payload successfully using postman but fails when using the proxy

Comment: you can enable the wirelog and see what are the http request and response crossing the esb .That will help you to troubleshoot the issue
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an SSL certificate issue. You need to import the x509 certificate from usertest.sciquest.com into the ESB's trustStore (esbHome/repository/resources/security/client-truststore). Use Java keytool for this / see my previous question ([Mutual SSL between ESB and unsecured back-end services , "Null cert chain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477898/mutual-ssl-between-esb-and-unsecured-back-end-services-null-cert-chain))